# What is this plant!

Tags: identification

I found it while walking in a (wild?) park in Germany. The leaves created a bowl shape container around the trunk where the water is collected! It has about 70 cm height

[image]

Comment: @pnuts  I am going to swat you upside the head.  You have been on top of these ID's before me and yet, why don't you make an answer?  Come on!  I mean I've spent hours on this and you la deee da already have it as a comment?  We might be wrong, heck, huge margin of error here (except Bamboo) but stick your neck out there more!  We've left that other ID open for you!  Gees, you are good.  Don't be afraid to make a mistake, heck, I do it all of the time and I am still alive...grins!

Comment: Sue sue sue.  You have just got to relax!  We need your feedback, negative, positive, right or wrong we know you are doing what you think is right and right you have been.  Maybe a few boo boo's but I can't remember them...at all.  Yes you are a pleaser.  It is interesting the position you've chosen on this site.  It is perfect for you but if I hear you put yourself down one more time I shall need to virtually shake you!  Arrogant?  Insensitive?  My goodness!  Not even close.

Comment: @Alper91 Unbelievable Wikipedia is banned in your country.  An eye opener.  Another question that should be included in our initial questionaire someday (@Niall C.).  Thanks for alerting us to that fact!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[teasel Dipsacus fullonum](http://www.aphotoflora.com/images/dipsacaceae/dipsacus_fullonum_wild_teasel_plant_young_14-06-08.jpg)

What a headache and good old pnuts was ahead of me! This is my guess for now...

Comment: That could very well be that one indeed!

Comment: I read the Wikipedia article and the paper mentioned there (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3060873). Then went today and saw that this plant really collects water to catch insects that according to that paper used by the plants to increase seed production.

Comment: Not to mention the Indians drank that water and used the spiked head for hair brushes.  Plants are so dang cool.  What can I say?  I've got to go read this paper.  These plants 'digest' insects, too?

Comment: I will cite the paper: "most wild plants will increase their growth (hence, potentially, reproductive output) given the additional nitrogen and phosphorus from decaying animal remains"

Comment: One caveat; too much nitrogen in relation with Phosphorous and Potassium will inhibit reproductive growth.  Decaying animal remains are sort of not good for composting, as is animal and human poo.  Those are different processes (anaerobic in part) and should not be done by home owners.  Until decomposition is complete the chemicals are not usable by the soil organisms.  Amazing cycle of life and death.

Comment: I just finished reading your paper and I would have loved to have done more research with teasel.  Fascinating stuff.  We are watching evolution taking place.  I'd like to see the research for the production of seed with the higher nitrogen.  Thank you Haider!

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure this is some kind of [**Thistle**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thistle).

More precisely this looks to me like a [Cirsium Canum](https://inpn.mnhn.fr/espece/cd_nom/91300) (you'll see there its rather located in east France, so could be in Germany too).

To get convinced, here is a picture of this I found [here](http://www.botanickafotogalerie.cz/fotogalerie.php?lng=cz&latName=Cirsium%20canum&czName=pch%C3%A1%C4%8D%20%C5%A1ed%C3%BD&title=Cirsium%20canum%20|%20pch%C3%A1%C4%8D%20%C5%A1ed%C3%BD&showPhoto_variant=photo_description&show_sp_descr=true&spec_syntax=species&sortby=lat):

[image]

Or it could be [Cirsium monspessulanum](https://species.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cirsium_monspessulanum)...

Here is a picture I found with that name, also similar to yours, but its also very close to *Cirsium Canum*:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Could well be. The park is in west of Germany and I have seen this purple flower around the park. I check it again tomorrow and mark you answer as correct.

Comment: One thing I am finding is that the picture shows obvious opposite leaves.